# Fill google sheets array with custom string

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

Sup, guys.

I have an array of elements, created from other sheets.
`{'Sheet1'!A2:A\'Sheet1'!B2:B;'Sheet2'!B2:B}`
And I want to include new column, custom string, as an element of array:
`{'Sheet1'!A2:A\"Qwerty"\'Sheet1'!B2:B;'Sheet2'!B2:B}`
But I'm receiving error of row count mismatch (999 average, but 1 in param #2).

How Can I fill array column with a static string?

Demo sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Amyd2IrVVoFHtRKmSkREQWywGwha_id7AQkMRrd5B2U/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Amyd2IrVVoFHtRKmSkREQWywGwha_id7AQkMRrd5B2U/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=FILTER({Sheet1!A2:A\Sheet1!X2:X&"Qwerty"\Sheet1!B2:B\
 CONCAT(Sheet1!C2:C&"€...";Sheet1!D2:D&"€")\Sheet1!E2:E\Sheet1!F2:F\Sheet1!G2:G};
 NOT(ISBLANK(Sheet1!A2:A));NOT(Sheet1!G2:G))
```

[image: 0]